# How to implement virtual scroll dropdown using Kendo in Angular?

Tags: angular, server-side, virtualscroll

I have a huge data set coming from a API. Rather than showing all those data in the dropdown at first, I want to call the server API and get the results when user scroll downs through the dropdown.

Can someone explain me how can I achieve this.

Comment: kendo dropdown has virtual property, you can use that to implement this.

Comment: Can we use it for server side API calls?

Answer (score 1):

you can refer kendo official documentation for this. [Kendo virtual dropdown](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/virtualization/)

Comment: Question: This does not seem to answer the original question. Does anyone know of a solution where when the user scrolls to the last visible item in a dropdownlist, an event can be triggered that fetches more data? This just seems to be a DOM enhancement which does not help with large record sets returned from an API that need to be paged. Thanks...